# How to assign a sub-level for multiple mid-level fields in a structure

Tags: matlab, structure, vectorization

I am trying to assign a sub-field to each element of a field.

This is achievable with a for-loop as shown below, however, I would like to vectorise the code.

```
n   = 3;
for i=1:n
    mesh.elem(i).x(1) = i;
    mesh.elem(i).x(2) = i^2;
end
```

I've investigated the use of deal, and tried approaches such as:

```
mesh.elem(1:n).x(1) = (1:n)-1;
```

but have always received errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 3;
exponents = 1:2;
values = bsxfun(@power, (1:n)', exponents);
values = num2cell(values, 2);
[mesh.elem(1:n).x] = deal(values{:});
```

That gets you:

```
>> mesh.elem.x

ans = 
    1    1


ans = 
    2    4


ans = 
    3    9
```

Comment: The bsxfun is a bit of overkill, but it gets the point across :)